# How to do a Merge with JDBCTemplate, SQL Server, and expected output

Tags: java, sql, merge, jdbctemplate

My query looks like this

```
MERGE dbo.myTable AS myt
USING (SELECT ? AS ID,
       ? AS Value) AS s
ON (s.id = myt.id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET myt.ApprovalUserId = s.ApprovalUserId
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT ( Value )
    VALUES  ( s.Value)
OUTPUT INSERTED.id;
```

My java code looks like this

```
jdbcTemplate.queryForInt(SQL, id, value);
```

But when I try to run I get

```
java.sql.SQLException: The executeQuery method must return a result set.
```

I would like to somehow extract the ID given by the merge "INSERTED.id".  Is there a JDBCTemplate method that I should be looking at? Or should I abandon merge and just do this with selects, updates, and locks?

I'm using Sql Server 2012, Java 6, and Spring jdbc 3.1.2.release

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final solution for me was to extend the JdbcTemplate class "StoredProcedure" and to throw my merge statement into a stored procedure.  The execute command returned all of the stored procedure results.